# Inverse Fermat's theorem for Pythagorean prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

In accordance with Fermat's theorem, a prime number $p$ will have the form $x^2 + y^2$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

**Question:** Is there a satisfactory description of all pairs $(x, y)$ such that $x^2 + y^2$ is a prime number?

Comment: It isn't even known that there are infinitely primes of the form $n^2+1$, though of course this would follow from standard conjectures.  Indeed there isn't a single polynomial (of degree $>1$) which is known to take infinitely many prime values.

Comment: what about the primes of the form $x^2+4y^2$? Is it also  imposyble find all such pairs?

Comment: Same problem. Don't get me wrong, it's a perfectly sensible question. It's just that almost nothing is known.

Comment: Actually, $2$ is a prime number which can be written as a sum of two squares, but $2\not\equiv1\pmod4$.

Comment: @lulu  Thank you!

Comment: Cf. [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture)

Comment: @Another User, Of course, odd prime numbers are meant.